# RegEx for matching emails with selected domains

Tags: python, regex

I want to list all email adresses with this:

```
dane[(dane.imie == "Rhea") & (dane.email == "[*]@ubusive.com")]
```

below code worked for me:

```
dane[(dane.imie == "Rhea") & (dane.email == "Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com@ubusive.com")]
```

so I tried to change the exact address Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com (fake email adress from generator) with something like this `[*]`

I solved this by adding regex, but I need to know how to implement simple solution for that, thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Can you give us some output, examples (more)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not hundred percent sure what you're looking for, but, as far as I understand you want to extract rows of a dataframe with specified imie ('Rhea' for istance) and email ending with '@ubusive.com' (no matter what's before it).

So in this situation (let's generate an example dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd

dane = pd.DataFrame({'imie' : ['Rhea', 'Rhea', 'Bob', 'Rhea'],
                     'email': ['Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com',
                               'Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com@ubusive.com',
                               'Bobbybear@ubusive.com',
                               'Rhea_Whitehouse7703@other.com']})
```

with dane being:

```
    imie    email
0   Rhea    Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com
1   Rhea    Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com@ubusive.com
2   Bob     Bobbybear@ubusive.com
3   Rhea    Rhea_Whitehouse7703@other.com
```

you just want row 0 and 1.
If your domain will always be 'ubusive.com', a simple way is this:

```
dane[(dane.imie == "Rhea") & (dane.email.str[-12:] == "@ubusive.com")]
```

which will give:

```
    imie    email
0   Rhea    Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com
1   Rhea    Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com@ubusive.com
```

if you want only the final domain (what comes past the final '@') a regular expression can be more useful.
This...

```
search_string = "@ubusive.com"
dane[(dane.imie == "Rhea") & (dane.email.str.extract("(@.*)")[0] == search_string)]
```

...will result in this:

```
    imie    email
0   Rhea    Rhea_Whitehouse7703@ubusive.com
```

and offers also the freedom to easily change the search string for domain name.

Hope this help, or, if it's not what you are looking for, please comment.

Comment: That's exactly what I expected!